# Writing a conditional statement in compass

Tags: css, compass-sass, compass

I have the following 4 classes.

```css
.editor-item{@extend .popover-icons; margin:10px auto;}
.editor-item-photobook {@extend .editor-item; background-position:-15px -19px; }
.editor-item-desc{ color:$white; width:98%; margin:0 auto;}

.editor-item-wrapper{
     border:1px solid $editor-menu-border; @include border-radius(2px);
     padding:15px; width:96px; height:96px; background-color:$editor-menu-background;
     &:hover{border:1px solid $hightlighteBorderInside-blue-fill; background-
     color: $hightlighteBorderInside-blue-fill; @include transition-duration(0.5s);}}
```

Now what I want is to write a conditional statement in COMPASS/SCSS, that detects when .editor-item-wrapper is hovered on. And when it is hovered on, I want editor-item-desc to fade out by 30%. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your HTML, but here is roughly how I would approach things:

1. Set up hover on `.editor-item-wrapper`.
2. Prepare an opacity transition on `.editor-item-desc`.
3. Access `.editor-item-desc` within the hover and control the fade out.

   ```
   .editor-item-desc {
     transition: 0.5s opacity;
   }

   .editor-item-wrapper {
     ...
     &:hover .editor-item-desc {
       opacity: 0.3;
     }
   }
   ```